# Neo4j-Core Ruby Bolt Connector very slow

Tags: ruby, neo4j

I have upgraded my Neo4j DB from 2.3.9 to 3.1.1 because I wanted to make use of the new binary Bolt protocol. After the upgrade I noticed that the Bolt connections is significantly slower than the "old" http connection.

I use the neo4j-core (7.0.5) gem with Ruby 2.4 on OSX. All my code accessing the Neo4j DB is encapsulated in a neo4j-query class. Within the "old" code I initialized the class with the following session that's used within all other methods of this class:

```
def initialize

    @session = Neo4j::Session.open(:server_db, 'http://localhost:7474/', basic_auth: { username: 'neo4j', password: 'XYZXYZXYZ'})

end
```

The @session object is used within multiple methods within this class with a satisfying speed.

After the migration to Neo4j 3.1.1 I used the following code to initialize the new adapter and the query session:

```
def initialize

    @neo4j_adaptor = Neo4j::Core::CypherSession::Adaptors::Bolt.new('bolt://neo4j:XYZXYZXYZ@localhost:7687')

    @session = Neo4j::Core::CypherSession.new(@neo4j_adaptor)

end
```

It works, but extremely slow. Up to 10x slower processing time compared with the "old" http connection. I investigated this effect a bit further and found out that there are hundreds of Threads created, while the "old" code just creates 4 Threads.

I changed the instance variable into a Class variable but with no effect. What am I doing wrong here? How should I instantiate the Ruby neo4j-core adaptor to ensure that it makes efficient use of the Bolt protocol?

Any help or hint pointing me to a solution is greatly appreciated.

Krid

Comment: Hello Krid. I have near the same problem with neo4j, it works very fast from cypher-shell and web-interface, but works extremely slow with neo4j-core. Have you found solution?

Comment: Hello Alexey, very late response but I haven't seen your question earlier. Unfortunately not. I was in contact with the developer of the adaptor. It appears that the speed issues haven't improved much so far. Suggestion was to stick with the HTTP for the time being,

Comment: Hello Krid. Thanks for your comment, we decided to switch to another graph db in the end.